# Using Scrapy with Python I fail to download images

Tags: python, image, download, scrapy

I'm trying to **scrape** a few images from a website. Sorry in advance, I am not very experimented with Python and it is the first time I try using scrapy.

I manage apparently to get all the images I need, but *they somehow get lost and my output folder remains empty*.

I looked at a few tutorials and all the similar questions I could find on SO, but nothing seemed to really work out.

**My spider:**

```py
from testspider.items import TestspiderItem
import datetime
import scrapy

class PageSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    
    name = 'page-spider'
    start_urls = ['http://scan-vf.co/one_piece/chapitre-807/1']

    def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = '.img-responsive'
        page = 1
        
        for imgPage in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
            IMAGE_SELECTOR = 'img ::attr(src)'

            imgURL = imgPage.css(IMAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first()
            title = 'op-807-' + str(page)

            page += 1

            yield TestspiderItem({'title':title, 'image_urls':[imgURL]})
```

**My items:**

```py
import scrapy

class TestspiderItem(scrapy.Item):

    title = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
```

**My settings:**

```
BOT_NAME = 'testspider'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['testspider.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'testspider.spiders'
DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS = 'testspider.items'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1,
}
IMAGE_STORE = '/home/*******/documents/testspider/output'
```

If you could be so kind as to help me understanding what's missing / what's incorrect, I would be grateful

Comment: Might just be that your setting should be `IMAGES_STORE` (note the plural...)

Comment: You're right on that @JonClements, now I have a folder created in my output!

Answer (score 1):

If you check a source code (usually `Ctrl+U` in a browser) you'll find that each `img` is a something like this:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-src=' https://www.scan-vf.co/uploads/manga/one_piece/chapters/chapitre-807/01.jpg ' alt='One Piece: Chapter chapitre-807 - Page 1'/>
```

As you can see you need to use `data-src` in your code instead of `src`:

```
IMAGE_SELECTOR = 'img ::attr(data-src)'
```

Comment: I made the correction and it indeed seems to be better!

From `'image_urls': ['data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7'],` to `{'image_urls': [' ' 'https://www.scan-vf.co/uploads/manga/one_piece/chapters/chapitre-807/06.jpg ']`

But there still seems to be some issues, my code works even less than expected

Comment: You can `strip()` each URL: `yield TestspiderItem({'title':title, 'image_urls':[imgURL.strip()]})`